# How to automate Microsoft word 2003 from WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, ms-office

I have a WPF window( using c# as code behind) that has some text fields.
What I want is, when the user presses the print button I want to take the information on these fields and use Microsoft word 2003 template. The template has some blank fields to be filled with these info coming from WPF widow.
**How would I automate word to do this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy:

1. Add a COM reference to the the "Microsoft Word 11.0 Object Library" (or use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word assembly).  You may have to in install Visual Studio Tools for Office System and/or browse to your the Primary Interop Assembly, depending on your VS.NET and Office versions and what else you have installed.
2. Create a Word.Application application object `var app = new Word.Application()`
3. Open the document with `var doc = app.Documents.Open(...)`.  Note that in C# 3.5 or below you must pass all parameters.  You can use a variable initialized to System.Reflection.Missing.Value for most of them.
4. Iterate through doc.Fields using foreach:  Read and parse the field's `.Code` range, then update the field's `.Result` range based on the text box content.

For example:

```
foreach(Field f in doc.Fields)
  if(f.Code.Text.Contains("lastName"))
    f.Result.Text = this.LastName;
  ...
```

This assumes your data context class has a DependencyProperty "LastName" that is bound from the XAML like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}" />
```

Comment: Great answer.  It came up while I was still composing mine, so I took my coding advice out in deference to yours and just kept the links to examples.

Comment: @Ray Burns: thanks, I have a template document with multiply Quick part and content control, but in `doc.Fields.Count` is 0. How to get fields in documnet?

Answer (score 2):

That you are doing this from a WPF window is immaterial.  The code behind should do all the automation.  Below are some resources that may help you with guidance or examples:

*Please note that it is not advisable to do this on a server.  I know your requirement is for Wpf, but that may end up getting involved in a Silverlight project.*

BTW: Using the COM objects is a little trickier than normal .NET objects, and the Office COM objects even more so:

**[Word Automation using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994229/how-to-automate-microsoft-word-2003-from-wpf)**

Note his initial declaration:

```
Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value()
Object oTrue = true;
Object oFalse = false;
```

This is because all method parameters are 'ref' parameters, so you can't pass the usual constants, `null`, `true`, and `false`.

[**Automation Samples Using Managed Code (Visual Basic or Visual C#)**](http://weblogs.asp.net/sbehera/archive/2003/12/12/43034.aspx)

A comprehensive list of automation samples.