# Open a window with Microsoft Word embedded?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, ms-office

Is it possible to open a window in C# with the Microsoft Word 2010 rich text editor embedded? This would make for a fantastic HTML/RTF editor. Obviously, this would only work on PCs that already have Word installed. Is this possible?

The obvious way is to use the `Word.Application` object from the [MS Word Object Library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994274/1294758) interop library, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Comment: We used to `DSOFramer`. I can't recommend it for you cause it has too many bugs and it doesn't support by Microsoft any more, but it's a good starting point :)